# Root View Controller's view not in the Window Hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiview-hierarchy

I have coded a login page which in my app delegate (under the method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) is set to be my root view controller with

```
[self.window setRootViewController:vc];
```

Where vc is the instantiation of my HomeVC.
This view loads correctly. I can enter in all of the data required for login just fine but as soon as I try and load another view I get

```
Warning: Attempt to present <RegisterVC: 0x7d07f520> on 
         <HomeVC: 0x7d374830> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I tried a little hack to be certain I got the top most view controller using the following code:

```
- (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

but, as I suspected, it only ever returned the current view controller, which is also the root view controller. It never even enters the while loop.

I cannot understand how the view controller I'm trying to call from is not on the hierarchy when it's not only displaying correctly but is also the *only* view on the hierarchy at all.

Edit 1: I'll include the AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method's section where I create and add the VC and the Navigation VC.

```
    UIViewController *vc = (HomeVC *)[[HomeVC alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([HomeVC class]) bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    [self.window setRootViewController:vc];
    //^^^This is the line I'm most suspicious of, is that correct?^^^
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:kDefaultBackgroundColor]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: What's the result of `[UIApplication sharedApplication].window.rootViewController` ? (you'll have to cast it to your UIApplicationDelegate's type)

Comment: Also it won't hit that while loop because `presentedViewController` is for VCs that are presented modally (which yours is not) via `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: I'm getting an error when attempting to compile your code, do you mean keyWindow instead of window? Because

 `AppDelegate * app = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].window.rootViewController` 

just ends up with an error saying "Property 'window' not found on object of type UIApplication *". 

If you meant keyWindow you'll notice that in my hack I actually use that exact code to get the top controller, which is what I end up returning. 

For that loop what _should_ I use to make it work?

Comment: Or should I make a dummy "root view controller" style class that just adds this HomeVC rather than having the root be the home view controller?

Comment: @MatthewBahr How you are loading the another view, from HomeVC?

Comment: @AvanishTag Yes, the HomeVC has a button, Register in this case, which then loads the register view controller. Except this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the root view controller of the window, which should be the navigation controller, and then get its top view controller.

try like this:if you are sure there is a viewController.presentedViewController then send includeModal as YES.

```
- (UIViewController *)topmostViewControllerFrom:(UIViewController *)viewController
                               includeModal:(BOOL)includeModal
{
    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedViewController)])
    return [self topmostViewControllerFrom:[(id)viewController selectedViewController]
                              includeModal:includeModal];

    if (includeModal && viewController.presentedViewController)
    return [self topmostViewControllerFrom:viewController.presentedViewController
                              includeModal:includeModal];

    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(topViewController)])
    return [self topmostViewControllerFrom:[(id)viewController topViewController]
                              includeModal:includeModal];

    return viewController;
}
```

Comment: Ok so having tried that none of the if statements evaluate true and it just returns the viewController passed in. Was worth a shot though.

Comment: This warning usually comes in Storyboards when it tries to perform 2 segues at the same time. I believe in appdelegate you are trying to present 2 viewcontrollers at the same time.

Comment: have you tried setting the navigation controller as the rootviewcontroller,[self.window setRootViewController:_navigationController];